# How can I prove (formally and elegantly) this function is homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On my book I found the following function:

$$\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to [0,2\pi)\times(-1,\infty), \quad r(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\to(\theta,r-1) $$

I think this function is an homeomorpshism, but I have trouble to prove it formally.

I think that $$\phi^{-1}: [0,2\pi)\times(-1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}, \quad (x,y)\to (y+1)(\sin x, \cos x) $$
is its inverse, and it is continuous.

> I have trouble to prove formally that also $\phi$ is continuous. I know that if I do the pre-image of an open rectangle I find an "open" piece of circular crown, but I don't feel comfortable with a function defined in this manner.
>
> In particular I was looking for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\} $ which is an indentification and such that $\phi\circ f$ is continuous, and so from this i can deduce that also $\phi$ is continuous; or something similar. Is possibile to prove that $\phi$ is continuous in this way? Are there other smart and elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be a homeomorphism, for example since the target space is contractible.

More explicitly it is homeomorphic to $[0, \infty) \times \mathbb R$, which does not really have the same "shape" as $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$, since the latter has "nontrivial loops."

If you've seen why $[0,2 \pi)$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic, the reason is similar.

---

You can see that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb R$  (a cyllinder) with basically that map though!

Take $(r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta)  \mapsto (\theta,r)$. Note that it is important that $0$ is removed since it doesn't make sense to talk about $\theta$ there. Note that it is bijective and that open maps sets map to open sets in the product topology for example.

Comment: Thank-you for the answer. I think I understand why the map $\phi$ can't be an homeomorphism.
But now... where my reasoning is wrong? I think (what I called) $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous, so $\phi$ is not continuous or is not true that what I called $\phi^{-1} $ is the inverse of $\phi$?

Comment: Your map $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \mapsto (\theta, r)$ in which sense has value in $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$? An element of $S^1 \times \mathbb{R} $ has the form of $((a,b,),c)$ not a pair.

Comment: $S^1$ can be parametrized by $\theta$ alone, you do not need to explicitly give $(x,y)$.

Comment: As for yours, look around any "tubular" neighborhood of $(2 \pi,(-1, \infty))$ and you should discover continuity problems with your inverse

Comment: "With your inverese" you mean $\phi^{-1}?$ I think $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous, but I think I have discovered continuity problems with $\phi$. For example, $A=[0,\pi /2) \times (0,1)$ is open in the codomain of $\phi$ but $\phi^{-1}(A)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$.